# Regex javascript help

Tags: javascript, regex

Like usual fighting with myself to understand regex and a I need a help

here is the string:

```
str = "function onclick(){location.href='http://localhost.com/default.aspx?sectionid=45674356-346-4447-3456-sddwerwertye&languageid=1';}";
```

what I need to after regex involved :

Output:

```
http://localhost.com/default.aspx?sectionid=45674356-346-4447-3456-sddwerwertye&languageid=1
```

so everything what is between :

"`...{location.href=`"  ----   and ---  "`;}`"

Thanks for any help !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str = "function onclick(){location.href='http://localhost.com/default.aspx?sectionid=45674356-346-4447-3456-sddwerwertye&languageid=1';}";  
var m = str.match("location\.href='([^']*)");
var url = m[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/location\.href='([^']+)'/
```

The url is contained within the first group.

```
   str = "function onclick(){location.href='http://localhost.com/default.aspx?sectionid=45674356-346-4447-3456-sddwerwertye&languageid=1';}";
   var pattern = /location\.href='([^']+)'/;
   if(pattern.test(str)) {
      return pattern.exec (str)[1];
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `/.*?'([^']*)/`?.  That's "ignore until the first apostrophe, grab everything that's not an apostrophe".

Answer (score 0):

```
str = "function onclick(){location.href='http://localhost.com/default.aspx?sectionid=45674356-346-4447-3456-sddwerwertye&languageid=1';}";
str.replace(/.*location.href='(.*)'.*/,"$1");
```

Would this work in your situation?